# Solution to system of stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W_{t}$ be a Wiener process. And let $\mu$, $\sigma$, $\lambda$ $\psi$ be real valued positive constants. Consider the following system of differential equations:

\begin{equation}\tag1
\frac{\dot{S}(t)}{S(t)} =  \psi\mu dt + \psi\sigma dW_{t} -\psi B(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dot{B}(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda}(S(t) - B(t))
\end{equation}

First question: how can we argue that a solution exists? Second question:does $S(t)$ have an analytical solution in terms of $W_{t}$?

Here is my (failed!!) attempt using guess and verify. I first solve for $B(t)$, which is straight-forward:

\begin{equation}\tag 2
B(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{s=0}^{t}S(s)e^{\frac{s-t}{\lambda}}ds
\end{equation}

Then I plug in (2) into (1) and solve out for $S(t)$ to get:

\begin{equation}\tag 3
S(t) = S(0)\exp\big\{\psi\mu t +\psi \sigma W_{t} - \frac{\psi}{\lambda}\int_{s=0}^{t}\int_{v=0}^{s}S(v)e^{\frac{v-s}{\lambda}}dv\big\}
\end{equation}

I guessed that:

\begin{equation}\tag 4
S(t) = S(0)\exp\big\{\psi\sigma W_{t} - \frac{\psi}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{t}W_{s}e^{\frac{s-t}{\lambda}}ds\big\}
\end{equation}

For the sake of demonstration, I also assume $\mu =0$ for now. Now equating expressions in the exponent of (3) and (4), we get:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t}W_{s}e^{\frac{s-t}{\lambda}}ds = \int_{s=0}^{t}\int_{v=0}^{s}S(v)e^{\frac{v-t}{\lambda}}dv
\end{equation}

Taking the derivative of both sides twice and after some algebra, we end up with $S(t) = dW_{t}$, so clearly my guess is incorrect.

I am starting to think there is no analytical solution? I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: A few considerations. When if we let $\sigma = 0$, then $S(t)$ has a solution $\mu$. This is easy to show. Second, note $B(t)$ is the exponential moving average of $S(t)$.

Comment: However, what if we modify the problem and assume:

\begin{equation}
\dot{B}(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda}(log(S(t)) - B(t))
\end{equation}

Comment: Your equation $(1)$ written in terms of stochastic integral is: $S_t = S_0 + \int_0^t \psi\mu S_u du + \int_0^t  \psi\sigma S_udW_{u} -\psi  \int_0^t B(u)S_ud(??)$. What should I put instead of $d(??)$? $du$, $dS_u$, $dW_u$ ?

Comment: I think $du$? Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I will answer my questions as I seem to have figured it out.

I will modify the question slightly (assuming $\mu =0$ and the modified $\dot{B}$ as below) so that the algebra is neater, but the same idea should work for the original question. Assume $\frac{\psi}{\lambda}<1$. We seek a solution to the system:

\begin{equation}\tag1
\frac{\dot{S}(t)}{S(t)} =   \psi\sigma dW_{t} -\psi B(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dot{B}(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda}(\log(S(t)) - B(t))
\end{equation}

I first solve for $B(t)$, which is straight-forward:

\begin{equation}\tag 2
B(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{s=0}^{t}\log(S(s))e^{\frac{s-t}{\lambda}}ds
\end{equation}

Now plugging in the solution for $B(t)$ into the expression for $\frac{\dot{S}(t)}{S(t)}$, we get:

\begin{equation}\tag 3
S(t) = S(0)\exp\big(\psi \sigma W_{t} - \frac{\psi}{\lambda}\int_{s=0}^{t}\int_{v=0}^{s}\log(S(v))e^{\frac{v-s}{\lambda}}dv ds\big)
\end{equation}

Define $\textbf{L}$ to be an operator that integrates the smooth value of its argument as follows. For (suitable) stochastic process X:

\begin{equation}
\textbf{L}X(t) = \int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{s}X(v)e^{\frac{s-t}{\lambda}}dvds
\end{equation}

We can apply $\textbf{L}$ recursively, for $L^{i}X$, $L^{i+1}X$ is defined as:

\begin{equation}
L^{i+1}X(t) = \int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{s} L^{i}X(v)e^{\frac{s-t}{\lambda}}dvds 
\end{equation}

I claim the following solution for random function $S$ satisfies (3):

\begin{equation}\tag 4
S(t) = S(0)\exp\big(\sigma\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\psi^{i+1}}{\lambda^{i}(-1)^{i+2}}L^{i}W(t)\big), S(0) = 1
\end{equation}

(I slightly abuse notation, writing W_{t} as W(s)) 
Plug in (4) into (3) to get

\begin{align}
S(t)&  = \exp\big(\psi \sigma W_{t} - \frac{\psi}{\lambda}\int_{s=0}^{t}\int_{v=0}^{s}\log(S(v))e^{\frac{v-s}{\lambda}}dv ds\big) \\\\
    &  = \exp\big(\psi \sigma W_{t} - \frac{\psi}{\lambda}\int_{s=0}^{t}\int_{v=0}^{s}\sigma\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\psi^{i+1}}{\lambda^{i}(-1)^{i+2}}L^{i}W(v)e^{\frac{v-s}{\lambda}}dv ds\big) \\\\
   & = \exp\big(\psi \sigma W_{t} + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sigma\frac{\psi^{i+2}}{\lambda^{i+1}(-1)^{i+3}}\int_{s=0}^{t}\int_{v=0}^{s}L^{i}W(v)e^{\frac{v-s}{\lambda}}dv ds\big)\\\\
  &  = \exp\big(\psi \sigma W_{t} + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sigma\frac{\psi^{i+2}}{\lambda^{i+1}(-1)^{i+3}}L^{i+1}W(t)\big)\\\\
&  = \exp\big(\psi \sigma L^{0}W(t) + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sigma\frac{\psi^{i+2}}{\lambda^{i}(-1)^{i+2}}L^{i}W(t)\big)\\\\
& = \exp\big(\sigma\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\psi^{i+1}}{\lambda^{i}(-1)^{i+2}}L^{i}W(t)\big)
\end{align}

As was to be shown.

(The  assertions I have not proved are 1) that the infinite sum at (4) is well-defined and 2) that the exchange of summation and integrals at the third step above is valid. I do no think these should be a problem)